# Restrict Input Type EditText Android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I need to restrict input type of EditText in Android such a way that user can enter only digits from 0-9 and user can enter one comma(,) in entire input.
    Example: **455,67**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom filter extends InputFilter could be wrote. You can look over the link.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/InputFilter.java

Answer (score 1):

try using following code, Hope it works :)

```
 android:inputType="text"
 android:digits="1234567890,"
```

Comment: I need to take only one , from user in his entire input

Comment: kk sorry for my answer,i was not clear with your questions.I would then suggest to use combination of InputFilter and textchangelistner.

Comment: I can give code snippnet if u are k with InputFilter or else regular expression is another option.

Comment: Never, ever use android:digits on its own, it will give you a full keyboard and when you try and use any other character that isn't a specified digit the app will crash

Answer (score 0):

writing this

`android:inputType="number"`

in XML attributes of edit text will do that for you